# IF Statements with Dates in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to create a formula for Contract Certainty the rules are as follows:

A - Order is before inception and Completed before inception
B - Order is before inception but completed after inception
C - Order is after inception and completed after inception

I have three columns: Inception (Column I), order (Column O) and Completed (Column P) and the cells are formatted to short date.

I have created the following formula constructed from IF statements.

```
=IF(AND(I101>O101,I101>P101),"A",IF(AND(I101>O101,I101<P101),"B",IF(AND(I101<O101,I101<P101),"C")))
```

However, the formula is returning 'False' rather than a letter grading.

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because your last IF statement is not complete :

> IF(AND(I101 < O101,I101 < P101),"C")

which means there is no else

and you didn't consider the case where

I101 < O101 and I101 > P101

so to solve the problem the last IF should be like that:

> IF(AND(I101 < O101,I101 < P101),"C", "ResultElse")

Comment: Thanks for this. :)
Also needed to put greater than or equal to in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Evaluate Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) to evaluate formulas step by step to figure out what might be wrong.

The formula can be "simplified" to something like this (formulas can have new lines with Alt + Enter):

```
=IF( I101 > O101, 
    IF( I101 > P101, "A", "B" ), 
    IF( I101 > P101, "C", "D" ) )
```

or maybe ( `Mid("ABC",4,1)` gives blank "" ):

```
=Mid("ABC",(I101>O101)*2+(I101>P101)+1,1)
```